# Efficient debugging method with ink!

Tags: ink, debugging

### Problem

- I always use the following method to debug ink!
- However, that method is not very efficient when implementing complex contracts.
- Furthermore, there is a demerit that many debug statements will be included and the source code will be messy.
- Please let me know if there is a more efficient debugging method.

### Run local node with debug option:

```
./node_exe --dev --tmp -lruntime=debug
```

### Sample Code

```
#[ink(message)]
pub fn test_function(&self) -> Result<bool,Error> {
  
  ink::env::debug_println!("# self.value:{:?} ",self.value);
  
  let mut value2 = 0;
  if self.value >= 5 {
    value2 = 50;
  }
  else if self.value >= 3 {
    value2 = 40;
  }
  else {
    return Err(Error::InvalidValue);
  }

  ink::env::debug_println!("# value2:{:?} ", value2);

  if value2 == 50 {
    return true;
  }
  else{
   return false;
  } 

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ink! currently don't have any dedicated debugger with features like breakpoints, watch expressions, call stack like the ones for Solidity. The only tool we got is `debug_println!`.

> However, that method is not very efficient when implementing complex contracts.

This is indeed true, but at the same time it can be quite powerful if you manage to isolate the problem. I can't say for sure why you feel it is inefficient without context or example.

Few recommendations from my side

- Do not use `unwrap()` or `panic()` anywhere in ink! contract, instead define error and use `Result<T, YourError>` as return type and propagate the error to top level method.
  Simple pseduo example,

```rust
fn inner_method(id: u32) -> Result<u32, MyError> {
    // no unwrap(), propogate error
    let a = do_something(id)?;
    let b = do_something_more(a);
    Ok(b)
}

#[ink(message)]
pub fn register_uuid(&mut self, id: u32) -> Result<u32, MyError> {
    // no unwrap(), even if some different error type map it to your error
    do_something_checks().map_err(|_| MyError::SomeError)?;
    // no unwrap()
    let a = inner_method(id)?;

    self.env().emit(Event { id });

    Ok(a)
}
```

This allows you to get more information out of your contract execution, if execution fails you can dry-run it to get the error to isolate the issue and effectively use `ink::env::debug_println` to debug.

> Furthermore, there is a demerit that many debug statements will be included and the source code will be messy.

If that is a problem for you, at best you can wrap the `ink::env::debug_println` [with conditional macro/method with different behaviour in release and debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39204908/how-to-check-release-debug-builds-using-cfg-in-rust) like this,

```rust
#[cfg(debug_assertions)]
fn log(msg: &'static str) {
    ink::env::debug_println!(msg);
}

#[cfg(not(debug_assertions))]
fn log(_msg: &'static str) {
    // no op, --release
}
```

Hope it helps!